# How do you trigger an Azure function via HTTP without providing a variable?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

How do you trigger an Azure function via HTTP without providing a variable?

Microsoft's documentation example [1] got an example where you have to provide a variable (name) in the URL. How can I remove all code associated with the variable such that it just uses an HTTP connection?

The reason for this is that I want to run my function using Azure Data Factory, but my function does not need an input

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python

Comment: Can you link to the documentation example (non-naked link)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what the actual problem is. Just remove the code that accesses the querystring like this:

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello there, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
```

and call it using the function url, for example https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=function_key_here